How to run two copies of youtube?
I can not find an option in the setting to allow dual youtube. any ideas ? I tried to install and clone app but did not work. I use Android 13.

Would running another YouTube client eg NewPipe be ok?

@FranckDernoncourt yes newpip work fine

I would also recommend NewPipe, it's essentially youtube premium for free. The issue with running NewPipe is that you cannot use your actual youtube account, you could import your subscriptions but it's not ideal. You are losing out on commenting and such.

As of right now, Android does not have this functionality included. Dev previews suggested for this to launch for Android 14 but this was not the case. Android 15 might get it, but that is just a guess.
However, depending on your device manufacturer, there might be options such as Dual App, Parallel Apps, etc. by Samsung, Vivo, OnePlus, etc...
As Frank suggested, another Youtube client such as NewPipe might be the solution for you, if adding a second account in the youtube app is not a acceptable solution for you.
Just as a warning: Google is cracking down on third party ad blockers for YT
and / or might go after 3rd party clients. Some say that using NewPipe can be riskty to use and result in an account ban, but that is something you need to decide

Yes I have dual app feature in my tablet but it list every app except youtube !

Try grayjay, it also allows you to get feeds from other streaming services, not just YouTube, and no ads.

Please link the source of grayjay
